# Suppress BaseGameUtils sign-in-popup when using Google Play Games Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using Google Play Games Services in connection with the BaseGameUtils-helper-library. On every launch of an activity extending `BaseGameActivity`, a popup with a `ProgressBar` saying "Signing in to Google+" pops up for a few milliseconds, even though the user may not have opted to sign in via Google+ at all. Is it possible to suppress this dialog? It should only be shown if the user is actively signing in to Google+, not when the activity is handling the sign-in-process in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have the source, you will have to edit it. I believe those utils and helpers are supposed to be examples, not libraries.
Removing the dialog is very easy though... you need to remove the `showProgressDialog` method.

Also notice that the default implementation will attempt connections on the `onStart` method since its `mAutoSignIn` variable is initialized to true.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I commented out `showProgressDialog(true);` in `connectNextClient()`. This way, the progress dialog will still be shown when the user actively clicks on "sign in", but not on automated reconnects after that.